# Adding layout to another layout in Qt [C++]

Tags: c++

Could anyone tell me why I'm getting error and how to fix it?

```
        QGridLayout* mainLayout = new QGridLayout;
        QGridLayout *leftLayout = new QGridLayout;
        QGridLayout *rightLayout = new QGridLayout;
        mainLayout->addLayout(leftLayout);
        mainLayout->addLayout(rightLayout);
        setLayout(mainLayout);
```

error I'm getting:
'error: no matching function for call to 'QGridLayout::addLayout(QGridLayout*&)'
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Qt4 Reference says:

> void addLayout ( QLayout * layout, int
>   row, int column, Qt::Alignment
>   alignment = 0 )

So you have to do:

```
mainLayout->addLayout(leftLayout, 0, 0);
mainLayout->addLayout(rightLayout, 0, 1);
```

Comment: And whay it gives me an error saying that I'm providing ref to pointer as an argument?

Comment: Probably because your compiler is first trying to pass the argument by reference. But if you pass the correct parameters as I showed you, you'll don't see error anymore (I expect).